# Tracking leak in a big async Perl process

Tags: perl, memory-leaks

I am sorry in advance - but this post will not contain a code sample.

I was assigned with a task to debug a memory leak in some module.

In this program I have a management object that holds Data and other Objects. The program uses async methods that updates the managment object from time to time.

I used a Perl module [`Devel::Peek`](http://metacpan.org/module/Devel::Peek) to dump the object, and I was curious about the reference count.

Since I am using a local variable to print this object - the parent refcount is always 1 as expected.

My 2nd Level - the real management object refcount is always bigger then 1.

All other levels are also always 1 as expected.

Here is an example:

```
SV = RV(0xbb3e244) at 0xbb3e238
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)
  RV = 0xcf19478
  SV = PVHV(0xd0e1f98) at 0xcf19478
    REFCNT = 6
    FLAGS = (PADMY,OBJECT,OOK,SHAREKEYS)
    STASH = 0x9b116a0   "<XXXXX>"
    ARRAY = 0xd0ff190  (0:106, 1:104, 2:34, 3:10, 4:2)
    hash quality = 105.4%
    KEYS = 210
    FILL = 150
    MAX = 255
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
    Elt "<XXXXX>" HASH = 0x10b5af01
    SV = PVIV(0xce05510) at 0xcf07ba8
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
      IV = 16200
      PV = 0xd0fc0d8 "16200"\0
      CUR = 5
      LEN = 8
    Elt "<XXXXX>" HASH = 0x3ebbb602
    SV = PV(0xd10c810) at 0xcfb4350
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
      PV = 0xd2008d8 "<XXX>"\0
      CUR = 4
      LEN = 8
    Elt "<XXXXX>" HASH = 0x1c7c0002
    SV = RV(0xcf197f4) at 0xcf197e8
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (ROK)
      RV = 0xd456ba0
      SV = PVHV(0xd66a11c) at 0xd456ba0
        REFCNT = 1
        FLAGS = (PADMY,OOK,SHAREKEYS)
        ARRAY = 0xd19a8d8  (0:3, 1:3, 2:2)
        hash quality = 111.4%
        KEYS = 7
        FILL = 5
        MAX = 7
        RITER = -1
        EITER = 0x0
        Elt "<XXXXX>" HASH = 0x2d2f24a1
        SV = RV(0xc2e3fcc) at 0xc2e3fc0
          REFCNT = 1
          FLAGS = (ROK)
          RV = 0xd550548
```

I want to understand the reference count process.

If I understand the management object Ptr is being accessed from several locations. The internal objects are being accessed only once from the management object.

Is it possible that if I update internal fields on the management object from several locations it will cause a memory leak?

Comment: You have made your question unnecessarily complicated. It looks like you have made an attempt to format it sensibly as the text contains several individual newlines that Stack Overflow treats as generic white space. But that isn't how *markdown* works. I have edited your post so that it is represented as I think you intended, but please roll back my changes if anything is wrong

Comment: Isn't the substance of your question ***"I want to understand the reference count process"***? In which case your question is off-topic. I can refer you to [*Perl references and nested data structures*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [*Perl Data Structures Cookbook*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) but you are asking about the internals of a complex and high-level programming language, and I think you should expect to devote several weeks to understanding how it works

Answer (score 1):

A typical problem within async (event driven) programs is that objects are often referenced from within callbacks which are attached to some event loop and that one has to be really careful to clean everything up on error. Strategic uses of `weaken` from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util) helps here a lot.

But once you have the mess it is really hard to debug. I usually use my own module [Devel::TrackObjects](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::TrackObjects) to track down objects which do not get destroyed as expected and consider it easier to use for this purpose than Devel::Peek. But Devel::TrackObjects it can only deal with objects and does not help with other kinds of circular references.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's hard to answer directly, without any sort of idea what you're actually doing.

But yes - perl uses reference counting to determine if memory is still 'in use'. It's perfectly possible to cause a circular reference, and thus that memory will never be eligible to 'free' and thus it will leak.

The way you can avoid this is via the `Scalar::Util` module, and the `weaken` function call - that allows a reference to exist, but not 'count' for reference counting.

Comment: Thanks 
I will look into that. 
I also try to understand the output of the Devel::Peek information. 
Like FLAGS info, ARRAY, KEYS, RITER, EITER, STASH, ELT
I can't find any documentation that explains what this entries represent.

Comment: @yanger, [illguts](http://search.cpan.org/dist/illguts/). // The only FLAGS you really care about are IOK, NOK and POK. These indicate whether a scalar contains an integer, float and/or string. // ARRAY is the pointer to the array of buckets. (You need not look at that.) // KEYS is the number of elements in the hash. // FILL is the number of buckets used. (You need not look at that.) // RITER and EITER probably store the state of the hash's iterator. (You need not look at that.) // Elt is short for elements. (It shows the key and to what it hashes, and is followed by a dump of the value.)

Comment: Other FLAGS of interest: ROK (contains a ref), OBJECT (blessed), COW (PV is being shared by more than one scalar).

Comment: So i have a follow up question - is there a limit to the number of keys in the hash? in the example i posted: "KEYS = 210 | FILL = 150 | MAX = 255" 
What will happen if i will have 256 KEYS?

Comment: Nothing much. Hashes can be considerably larger comfortabley.